# unexpected symbol near '\' when loadstring byte

Tags: string, lua, escaping

When trying to create a tool that converts a Lua code into byte and then `string.dump` it I got an error.

Code used :

```
s = [[
print("hello lua user")
]]

local byte = ""

for i = 1, s:len() do
byte = byte.."\\"..tostring(s:byte(i))
end

-- Creating the function to use in string.dump
f, err = loadstring(byte)

print(err)

local output = string.dump(f)
```

The error in title comes from printing `err`

The weird is that if I print(byte) and then manually paste it inside `loadstring` quoted, it works.

Manually pasting it won't work since I need it to be automated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Lines 5-9 seem to be doing nothing other than turning the code into `\ddd` with 2-3 digits, which is not valid Lua nor is it "bytecode".

Comment: @Advert trying to string.byte and then string.dump to hide the strings

Comment: You have to do it the other way around then.

Comment: I think you mean to do something like this: http://ideone.com/FDmsYf

Comment: Of course, if you `print(<\string>)`, you'll see the strings. If you want to hide it there, you can use a cipher, etc. etc. But it won't be impossible to decode, in the end -- but you can make it painful to do so.

Comment: Turning string literals into a bunch of concatenated `string.byte` calls is not very performant, and pretty easy to reverse.

Comment: @Advert thanks, i think i will just use a cipher and string.dump, or maybe just switch all strings for string.char

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing with escaped sequences in Lua. Let's check a simpler example:

In a system using ASCII, `'\97'` is equivalent to `'a'`, so

```
print('\97')
print('a')
```

Both lines print the character `a`, but what you are converting is like this:

```
print('\\97')
```

This prints `\97` itself, not `a`.

---

To make your code work, add these lines after you get `byte`.

```
local f1, err1 = loadstring("return '" .. byte .. "'")
byte = f1()
```

This call to `loadstring` converts a string like `'\\97'` back to `'\97'`.

Comment: but if I were to s = "\\97" print(loadstring(s)()) it should print a right? that was my initial idea

Comment: @Mojimi Still no. I updated the answer to add the solution. Think about what this extra `loadstring` does.